# Undefined reference to gdk function

Tags: gtk, c

I have a gtk program in which I am trying to call a gdk function. I have the following include files:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
```

and am compiling with the following:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 cairo glib-2.0 gdk-2.0` gtk_fixed.c Widget.c Node.c Line.c
```

I am getting the following error:

```
undefined reference to `gdk_device_ungrab'
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this [link](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/2.24/gdk-Input-Devices.html)

There is no grab method in Gdk 2.

There is a grab method in [Gdk 3](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/GdkDevice.html#gdk-device-grab),though.

Did you read the docs for Gdk 3?